# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/chart/ChartPanel when creating a runnable jar - why?

Tags: java, jar, runnable

im using for one of my projects JFreeChart. When I create an runnable jar everything is okay. But when I create a jar (because I want to add my source code in the jar), then a NoClassDefFoundErrorException occurs - what is wrong here?

Comment: Please describe how you create the jar file and how you try to start your application.

Comment: I select Export -> jar (not runnable jar) -> then checkboxing : export generated class files and resources/ export java source files and resources and name of outputfile (browse button) -> next -> next -> choosing under Jar manifest Specification the mainclass of the project - finished!

Comment: stating the application just by: java -jar myFile.jar